# Анимированный интерактивный favicon

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript

Интересует такой вопрос, каким образом сделана favicon на сайте [megalyrics.ru](http://megalyrics.ru), когда запускаешь какой-нибудь трек?

Изначально мысль была, что через js/php генерится статический изображение эквалайзера, и заменяется. Но, разные пользователи слушают разные треки и к тому же браузер это дело хорошо кеширует, потому явно не так происходит. К тому же это ж сколько в день миллиардов генерации изображения, пусть даже такого маленького.

Есть у кого какие идеи?

**UPD**
Нашел [такое](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les1060/index.html), вроде то, что нужно, но все-же получается сколько изображений должно генериться в плане эквалайзера....

Comment: То, что по вашей ссылке - полезнейшая вещь, спасибо). А генерить можно и на стороне клиента, canvas'ом.

Comment: Да не за что ))) Написал к ответу коммент по этому поводу, а потом уже ваш прочитал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во время проигрывания трека favicon подменяется [при помощи JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically/260876#260876). Однако вместо полноценных ссылок используется трюк с префиксом "[data:](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL)". Т.е. во время проигрывания с определенным интервалом генерируется favicon сл. вида:

```
<link id="sm2-favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAVklEQVQ4jaXJoQ2AQBjF4A6HxWDQGMRpDIYpWYAFWOEQ6Htp8jf5VAGuAPE5A/M5AvPrtcB89sB8tsD8emtgPktgPnNgfrWXPvQ3BcBDHzKfmz5kfrUPbn11Htae9cEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
```

Сами данные картинки могут как генерироваться на JS, так и загружаться сразу все возможные варианты с сервера (если не ошибаюсь, там получается всего 64 варианта, 2 колонки по 8 делений)

PS Парсер не может разобрать вторую ссылку. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL

Comment: Что значит не может? У меня отлично открывается, дублирую http://ruseller.com/lessons/les1060/index.html

За ответ спасибо. На самом деле там вариантов больше, т.к. каждое деление имеет 3 вида заполнения, а не 2, т.е. заполняется по 1/3. Ну наверное тогда логично сделать все изображения и отдавать нужные. Но опять же, этож несколько раз в секунду отправлять запрос на сервер, с данными трека, проверять их, искать нужную картинку и отдавать назад. 

Я это к тому, что на сервер нагрузка ведь бешенная идет. В смысле не по объему данных, а по количеству запросов.

Comment: Хотя, если подумать, возможно это делается все на стороне клиента. Т.е. кэшируются все картинки и общение браузера(трека) через js идет уже не с сервером, а с браузером клиента и его кешем. Наверное да, скорее всего так оно и есть.

Comment: > Что значит не может?

Попробуйте вставить эту ссылку: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL

> На самом деле там вариантов больше

Все равно, количество возможных вариантов сильно ограниченно, а размер favicon в base64 порядка 200 байт всего. Т.ч. даже если там по 16 делений на столбик, то получается 16*16*200 = 51 200 байт.

> Но опять же, этож несколько раз в секунду отправлять запрос на сервер

Еще раз. Запросов на сервер не идет *вообще*, т.ч. нагрузка на сервер *отсутствует* полностью. Почитайте ссылку в вики, которую я выложил выше.

Comment: Я думал вы про мою ссылку =)

Попробовал в адресную строку вбить из wiki
**`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhMAAwAPAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAMAAw  AAAC8IyPqcvt3wCcDkiLc7C0qwyGHhSWpjQu5yqmCYsapyuvUUlvONmOZtfzgFz  ByTB10QgxOR0TqBQejhRNzOfkVJ+5YiUqrXF5Y5lKh/DeuNcP5yLWGsEbtLiOSp  a/TPg7JpJHxyendzWTBfX0cxOnKPjgBzi4diinWGdkF8kjdfnycQZXZeYGejmJl  ZeGl9i2icVqaNVailT6F5iJ90m6mvuTS4OK05M0vDk0Q4XUtwvKOzrcd3iq9uis  F81M1OIcR7lEewwcLp7tuNNkM3uNna3F2JQFo97Vriy/Xl4/f1cf5VWzXyym7PH  hhx4dbgYKAAA7`**

Картинка, прикольно )) Но посмотрите "свойства изображения", и ее размер ;)